# In Unreal Engine how to simulate a key press?

Tags: unreal-engine4

Unreal Engine 4.
I want to press a key within a bp automatically.

How to simulate a key press in unreal for example "Left alt" ?

The Ue4 does not have a blueprint for this.

Answer (score 1):

RAMA's Victory plugin has a bp for this
https://github.com/EverNewJoy/VictoryPlugin

[image]